# How to Add Report Viewer tools in Visual Studio 2022 C# Windows form application

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdlc, reportviewer

I can't add Report Viewer tools in Visual studio 2022 .I am using c# desktop application.

Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you need to install [Microsoft RDLC Report Designer 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio2022)

Comment: @Yunnosch please check my answer post date first before you say im repeating other answers

Comment: You caught me and are of course right. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to download RDLC extension for Reporting "Microsoft.RdlcDesigner.vsix" From the below link:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio2022

Then try to install at your machine by closing Visual Studio before installation. Then restart your machine then you will be able to see option for Report or Report Wizard to create and design reports.

Answer (score 0):

Install ReportViewerCore.Winform nuget package and also Microsoft RDLC Report Designer 2022 extension from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio2022

Comment: You are repeating what both other answers have already proposed. So I assume that the purpose of your post is merely to agree/confirm or thank for those existing answers. None of that is considered an answer here. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

**RDLC Report item template, Report Application project template, and RDLC report Designer**

Install [Microsoft RDLC Report Designer 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio2022) extension on Visual Studio, to add adds "Report Application" project template, and "RDLC Report" item template and the "RDLC Report Designer" to Visual Studio.

*Note:* If you create a "Report Application" project, since it has preinstalled Nuget package of ReportViewer, then you don't need to explicitly install the package yourself. Make sure you rebuild the project after created.

**Add ReportViewr Control to toolbox of WinForms application**

Install [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms) Nuget Package on a .NET Framework Windows Forms project, to add ReportViewer control to toolbox. .

*Note:* It doesn't include the RDLC report template and the report designer, so you usually need to install above VS extension as well. But you don't necessarily need to create "Report Application", a normal Windows Forms .NET Framework app, and then installing the NuGet package does the same thing as the Report Application app (without a wizard at the beginning). Make sure you rebuild the project after you installed the package

**Reporting Service Reports project template, RDL item template, and RDL report designer**

Install [Microsoft Reporting Services Projects 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio2022) which is for creating Report `.rptproj` projects which is for Reporting Service Reports (RDL);

*Note:* It doesn't add the RDLC report template or Report Application project template, or RDLC report designer, and you only want it if you want to have a report server project and deploy the project to SSRS.

**.NET CORE 3.1, and .NET 5+**

Above solutions works for *.NET Framework* projects. If you want ReportViewr for *.NET 5+ , or .NET Core 3.1+* you may want to use [ReportViewer Core](https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore)

**VS 2022 Windows Forms RDLC Report and Report Viewer - Step by step example**

To see a detailed step by by step example, take a look at following post:

- [Visual Studio 2022 - RDLC reports and ReportViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75152761/3110834)