# Installing and using ReportViewer in Visual Studio 2022 Windows Forms

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, rdlc, reportviewer

I have tied several times to install the report designer and report viewer into studio 2022. The install for the report designer worked fine. I can create wizard and do-it-yourself .rdlc reports.

I'm totally new to this. All of the online tutorials about using the report tools start with 'drag a report viewer into a form and start configuring it.'

Installing the report viewer to the toolbox is from the nuget package and then the dll from browsing the project folder for the dll.
Unfortunately when I added the report viewer to the form from the toolbox, the report viewer drops below the form and will not let me configure it as in all the tutorials.

I have tried the report viewer 2010, version 11, version 12, and version 15 packages including the one that said it fixed a problem with the package not installing all the needed dlls.

According to the tutorials there should be a smart tag. This does not happen, and I cannot see any properties i can link to the report. I've tried linking the reportviewer to the rdlc by putting it into the localreport ReportEmbeddedResource property but nothing shows when you run the code.

Have I not set this up correctly, or is the tool not working?

Comment: Install [Microsoft RDLC Report Designer 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio2022) VS extention, and then install [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms) NuGet package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install the followings:

- [Microsoft RDLC Report Designer 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio2022) VS extension which adds required project, item templates and designers to VS.
- [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms) NuGet package which adds the report viewer control to the toolbox.

Note 1: this answer is targeting *.NET Framework* projects. If you want ReportViewr for *.NET 5+ , or .NET Core 3.1+* you may want to use [ReportViewer Core](https://github.com/lkosson/reportviewercore)

Note 2: You may find some useful information in [Add the Report Viewer control to a new Windows Forms project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-ver16&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#add-the-report-viewer-control-to-a-new-windows-forms-project)
 docs article as well.

Note 3: There is an extension [Microsoft Reporting Services Projects 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio2022) which is for creating Report `.rptproj` projects which is for Reporting Service Reports (RDL); It doesn't add the RDLC report template or Report Application project template, or RDLC report designer.

#### Visual Studio 2022 - RDLC reports and ReportViewer in Windows Forms

Here is a step by step example:

1. Install [Microsoft RDLC Report Designer 2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio2022), and restart VS.
2. Create a new **Windows Forms .NET Framework** project.
3. Install the [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms) NuGet package, which will add ReportViewer to the toolbox of your project.

   *Note:* Optional - You may want to install [Microsoft.SqlServer.Types](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types) as well to get rid of a warning which complains about version of the library.
4. Add the following class to your project:

   ```
   public class Product
   {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
5. Rebuild the solution (project).
6. *Add New Item* > *Report* (You can search or find it under C# items), and lets call it Report1.rdlc.
7. Then open the report in design mode (double click). Then *Report Data window* > *New* > *DataSet*

   Note: The shortcut key for the window is Ctrl + Alt + D, if it's not open.
8. In the DataSet Properties window, click on *New ...* in front of DataSource dropdown, and choose *Object Data Source*, follow the wizard and choose the Product class and the data source and complete the wizard. Make sure the data source and product class are selected, and then close the new data source window.

   [image]

   Note: If you forgot to build the project after creating Product class, the class doesn't appear in the list of classes for data source.
9. Open *ToolBox* > Drop an instance of *Table* on the report, hover the mouse over the first cell of the second row and click on DB Icon to bind it to Id column, and do the same on second cell of the second row to bind it to Name column. Then save the report:

   [image]
10. Open the form in design mode, and from ToolBox, drop an instance of *Report Viewer* on the form. You can find it on top or the toolbox under Microsoft Sql Server category.

    [image]
11. Click on the smart tag (the arrow), and choose Report:

    [image]
12. Click on the *Choose Data Source*, and in the window, choose Product. It will add a productBindingSource to your form:

    [image]
13. Double click on form and add the following code:

    ```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.productBindingSource.DataSource = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product(){ Id=1, Name= "Lorem" },
            new Product(){ Id=1, Name= "Ipsum" },
        };
        this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }
    ```
14. Run the project and see the result:

    [image]

Comment: The bit that is missing in your answer which appears to be the crucial step is to install the Microsoft extension "Microsoft Reporting Services Projects.". I followed the step by step guide from Abdulkarim M. Jamal Kanaan here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1XnkKPwwD4 and it worked. Thank you both for your input.

Comment: Thanks, I added a Note 3 to the answer. "Microsoft Reporting Services Projects" is for RDL files, not RDLC, and it's useful for Report Server Projects, now Windows Applications. It may do the trick but  the other extension that I mentioned is more accurate "Microsoft RDLC Report Designer 2022". For your ReportViewer issue, they both *may* help, however none, is related to the ReportViewer design-time support.

Comment: I tried to explain the [differences and roles of the extensions and packages here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75153877/3110834).